# How to detect whether Printer is attached to your computer or not in Java?

Tags: java

I am creating one GUI in swing Java. I have to use one button " Print " which will directly start printing the file I have set without opening the default Print dialog box.
I have to check first whether printner is attached to my computer or not ?

Comment: Just wanted to comment that if this GUI is just for your personal use, that's fine.  But if you plan on others using it, it's bad design to just decide for the user what printer to use.  Could go to the 36" plotter.

Also, your last sentence is a statement with a question mark at the end.  It's not really a question?

Comment: Just completed my answer to check if the printer is connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be using [PrintServiceLookup](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html)?

> Implementations of this class provide lookup services for print services (typically equivalent to printers) of a particular type.

```
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT;
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestHashAttributeSet();
aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
PrintService[] pservices =PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);
if (pservices.length > 0) {
    DocPrintJob pj = pservices[0].createPrintJob();
    //....
}
```

Note: the number of PrintService should be at least one iff there is a printer. Potentially at least 2 if there is an *actual* printer, since you can have pure software printers installed on your computer. See also [this thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=600743).

Depending on the platform and jdk, it can have [some bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5109523), but otherwise, the following method is supposed to at least list the printers:

```
import java.awt.print.*;
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;

public class ShowPrinters {
    
    public ShowPrinters() {
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocFlavor myFormat = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        PrintService[] services =PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(myFormat, aset);
        System.out.println("The following printers are available");
        for (int i=0;i<services.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("  service name: "+services[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

---

In this [eclipse code source](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.gmf/plugins/org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.printing.render/src/org/eclipse/gmf/runtime/diagram/ui/printing/render/dialogs/PrinterBlock.java?root=Modeling_Project&view=co), you have see the use of PrinterState to check if the printer is actually connected:

```
AttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet(
    new PrinterName(printerName, Locale.getDefault()));
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
    DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE,
    attributes);
PrintService printService = services[0];
PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributes = printService.getAttributes();
PrinterState printerState = (PrinterState) printServiceAttributes.get(PrinterState.class);
```

Check if printerState is not null. Note: this might not be always enough (see [this thread](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Java-1046/know-weather-printer-1.htm)).

Comment: Yes, I am getting the name of printer here,but my printer is not physically attached to my computer.How should I check it first before proceeding ?

Comment: I would think that as long as the printer has been "installed" on the box it should be available via the above code whether it is a local or network printer. I would test it out but I dont have either option available at the moment. :-)

Comment: @VonC do you know why printerState may be always null even printer is switched on and actually connected?

Comment: @whizzzkey no I do not know.